# pay for goods with tokens

Tags: tokens, erc-20, ropsten

I pay for goods with tokens. But after the first call to the function, tokens are not removed from the wallet. Please tell me why when I call the function for the first time, tokens are removed, but are not removed during the next calls? Thanks

```
function placeBid(uint amount)  public notOwner returns(bool) {
    require(auctionState == State.Running);
    require(count>=amount);
    goods[msg.sender].add(amount);
    startPrice = startPrice*100000000*amount;
    bids[msg.sender].add(startPrice);

    trc20.approve(msg.sender, address(this), startPrice);
    // Move to tokens to contract address
    trc20.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), startPrice);
    count = count-amount;
    startPrice=0;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit difficult to say as this is a part of a bigger contract. But here's my guess.

At the end of the function you are setting your `startPrice` to be zero. Next time the function is executed the multiplication of `startPrice = startPrice*100000000*amount` gives always 0 so you always approve the move of 0 tokens.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, change this:

```
goods[msg.sender].add(amount);
```

To this:

```
goods[msg.sender] = goods[msg.sender].add(amount);
```

And this:

```
bids[msg.sender].add(startPrice);
```

To this:

```
bids[msg.sender] = bids[msg.sender].add(startPrice);
```

---

You probably also want to change this:

```
startPrice = startPrice*100000000*amount
```

To this:

```
startPrice = startPrice.mul(100000000).mul(amount)
```

And this:

```
count = count-amount
```

To this:

```
count = count.sub(amount)
```

Comment: Thanks for the amendment. I'm new here)

Comment: @malysh: You're welcome. Please note that you have posted very partial information, for example, what is `startPrice` and how it is initialized (and it goes for all the other variables in your code), which makes it rather impossible to actually pinpoint all the problems in your code. I pointed out only the obvious ones.